# How to move data from column to row based on Criteria

Tags: excel

I can't think of a more specific title for this question, sorry.

I have some data that's been extracted from a large database, however one column contains bullet points, and excel has put each bullet point into a new row in column A. I would like a formula to take all the data from this column and add it to the relevant row.

Not all entries have lists, and not all the lists are the same length, so I need to find a way of telling excel which entry links which which row as well.

Here is an example of the data I'm working with

```
Code         Name       Info       List
A10          A10 name   A10 info   List Item 1
List Item 2  
List Item 3    
A11          A11 name   A11 info   
A12          A12 name   A12 info   List item 1
List Item 2
A13          A13 name   A13 info   List item 1
List Item 2
List Item 3
List Item 4
A14          A14 name   A14 info
A15          A15 name   A15 info
A16          A16 name   A16 info

etc....


I would like it to look like this
Code         Name       Info       List         List 2        List 3     
A10          A10 name   A10 info   List Item 1  List Item 2   List Item 3
A11          A11 name   A11 info   
A12          A12 name   A12 info   List item 1  List Item 2
```

...etc.......

Is this possible?

I've tried a number of approaches already, but I'm somewhat of a novice.

Comment: So, I assume "List Item 1" is not the actual data in the field?  So, would it be safe to say that Column A ("Code") will only be "A10", "A11", "A##"?  How do we know what list items each will be? Will the "List Item 1" have a reference to "A10"?

Comment: Is there a common feature to either the List Item elements, or to the A10... elements? Or some feature that separates the two groups? Will A10... always start With an a, or is that just a placeholder name?

Comment: What approaches have you tried?  Where have you run into problems?  Is this a one-off problem, or will the solution need to be run multiple times?

Comment: The data in my example is just an example, it's not representative of what I'm actually working with.
`
`
I can give any data a reference to the code, i.e. "A10" in this example.
There are some common features for all list item elements, they all contain the text "&li;" The codes always have a letter followed by numbers (i.e. A274, B9025). 
`
`          
This is a one off problem. So far I have tried using IF and  ISNUMBER functions to find cells with "&li;" and that contain the code in column A. However it either picks up nothing or picks up everything instead of just the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

In E2:

```
=IF(LEN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+COLUMN()-4,2)))=0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+COLUMN()-4,1)),"")
```

Essentially, if column B in the row below is blank, grab the (list) value from column A.

Fill this to the right across row 2 (from column E to as far right as you need). Then fill down.

When you're done, copy/paste values to get rid of formulas and then sort on col A and delete any list item rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is really written "A#" in column A of every row you desire...

```
dim i as integer
'puts the list otems at the end of the previous row 
for i = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    if not range("A" & i) Like "A#" then
        if range("E" & i - 1) = "" Then'I assumed only 3 possible bullets, but suit this to your liking. If there are many bullets put this in a loop.
            range("E" & i - 1) = range("A" & i)
        ElseIf range("E" & i - 1)(,2) = "" Then
            range("E" & i - 1)(,2) = range("A" & i)
        ElseIf range("E" & i - 1)(,3) = "" Then
            range("E" & i - 1)(,3) = range("A" & i)
            Rows("i").delete Shift:=xlUp 'deletes the line
        end if 
next
```

Comment: PLEASE save a copy of your file before doing this, as I have not tested it.